# Two files, conditional compile using preprocessor

Tags: c, conditional-compilation, pebble-sdk

I have two C files, one called `main.c` the other `batterysaver.c`. Instead of including the code that I have in `batterysaver.c` into the `main.c` file, and using a conditional compile, I want to have two separate files, but be able to set which file is compiled given a preprocessor directive. Is this possible?

**This is the `main.c` file's header:**

```
//standard header
#include "pebble.h"
#include "iota.h"
#define BATTERY false

//app-specific data
Window *window; //obvious window is obvious
TextLayer *time_layer; //time layer

#if !BATTERY
*REST OF FILE STARTS HERE, THEN AT THE END*
#endif
```

**This is the `batterysaver.c` file's header:**

```
#include "main.c"

#if BATTERY
*REST OF FILE STARTS HERE, THEN AT THE END*
#endif
```

I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. A C-file (almost) never includes another C-file. They are both compiled to an object file, and the object files are linked to the executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including a `.cc` file in another `.cc` file is indicative of unclean design.

You can conditionally compile in/out portions of the code in `main.cc` and `batterysaver.cc` based on whether `BATTERY` has been defined or not.

If that doesn't work, you have to ask yourself how you can put common declarations in a `.h` file and include the `.h` file in both the `.cc` files.

**`my_common.h`**

```
#ifndef MY_COMMON_H
#define MY_COMMON_H

//standard header
#include "pebble.h"
#include "iota.h"
#define BATTERY false

//app-specific data
extern Window *window; //obvious window is obvious
extern TextLayer *time_layer; //time layer

#ENDIF
```

**`main.cc`**

```
#include "my_common.h"

Window *window; //obvious window is obvious
TextLayer *time_layer; //time layer

#if !BATTERY
*REST OF FILE STARTS HERE, THEN AT THE END*
#endif
```

**`battarysaver.cc`**

```
#include "my_common.h"

#if BATTERY
*REST OF FILE STARTS HERE, THEN AT THE END*
#endif
```